# Factory Girl and nested attributes validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, factory-bot, nested-attributes

I have a model Company which accepts nested attributes for Recruiters model. I need to have validation in my Company model that at least one recruiter was created during Company creation.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :recruiters, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :company
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :recruiters, reject_if: ->(attributes) { attributes[:name].blank? || attributes[:email].blank? }, allow_destroy: true

    validate { check_recruiters_number } # this validates recruiters number

    private

    def recruiters_count_valid?
       recruiters.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).count >= RECRUITERS_COUNT_MIN
    end

    def check_recruiters_number
       unless recruiters_count_valid?
           errors.add(:base, :recruiters_too_short, count: RECRUITERS_COUNT_MIN)
       end
    end
end
```

Validation works as expected but after adding this validation I have a problem with FactoryGirl. My factory for company looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :company do
        association :industry
        association :user
        available_disclosures 15
        city 'Berlin'
        country 'Germany'

        ignore do
            recruiters_count 2
        end

        after(:build) do |company, evaluator|
            FactoryGirl.create_list(:recruiter, evaluator.recruiters_count, company: company)
        end

        before(:create) do |company, evaluator|
            FactoryGirl.create_list(:recruiter, evaluator.recruiters_count, company: company)
        end
    end 
end
```

In tests, when I do

```
company = create(:company)
```

I get validation error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Company has to have at least one recruiter
```

When I first build company and then save it, the test passes:

```
company = build(:company)
company = save
```

Of course, I don't want to change all my tests this way to make them work. How can I set up my factory to create associated model during creation Company model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `validate { check_recruiters_number }` is unreasonable. Remove it.

Why? You need to have a valid company id to save recruiters, but your validator prevent company to be valid because it has no recruiters. This is in contradiction.

Comment: But I need to check if company gets any recruiters attributes. In other words I don't want to create company without recruiter. Moreover application works as expected: if I add recruiter in the company form, company is created. If I don't the validation failed.

Comment: @wawka, I just read your question again and found your second trial did not success yet, from the evidence I saw. `company.save` won't throw any error, so you may think it passed. But if you try `company.save!` you will see it. The validator you asked is impossible in pure model level. It can be done through Form Object, or add a judger in controller to test reruiters params. In short, company **must be saved at first** then the associated recruiters can be created otherwise **company_id is blank** and thus invalid to save.

Comment: Also the validation is not in good logic. When Model A has many Model B, A is independent, is free. It's creation should not be dependent on B at all. B is dependent on A, of course, without A you can't create B.

Comment: Thanks Billy. This explains me a lot. I found an article about validating nested attributes: http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails. So I thought it's just fine to do so. Now, I understand why it's not. Thanks!

Comment: @wawka, thanks for the link, nice article. A notice is all of his validators on Model B dose not depend on Model A, even the count is a constant.

Comment: hmm..., but validation of Model B is invoked during validation of Model A. He also use validate method in Model A. So it depends on Modal A, I think. If the method check_offices_number return false, Model A won't be valid, right?

Comment: @wawka, yes, of course, if validation failed the object can't be saved.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I have similar problem and I solved it with the following code (rewritten to match your case):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :company do
        association :industry
        association :user
        available_disclosures 15
        city 'Berlin'
        country 'Germany'

        ignore do
            recruiters_count 2
        end

        after(:build) do |company, evaluator|
            company.recruiters = FactoryGirl.build_list(:recruiter, evaluator.recruiters_count, company: company)
        end
    end 
end
```